# WPF application crashes with all exceptions enabled and all unhandled exceptions being handled

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have handled all the unhandled exceptions:

```
DispatcherUnhandledException
FirstChanceException
UnobservedTaskException
Application.ThreadException
CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

In Exception Setting i have CLR Exceptions enabled.

One common error that has been logged to my output(from firstchanceexception handler) is: "The 'program [9784] ' has exited with code - 1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'"

But still my WPF app crashes without breaking in any of handlers or in code.

What other handlers needs to be handled for detecting the crash? or avoiding from wpf app to crash.

Comment: Sounds like it's in unmanaged code, have you checked the event viewer?

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException?

Comment: Firstchangeexception handler is usually a bad idea. It catches way too many spurious errors. Like binding "failures" that are just temporary.  I usually handle AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException instead, as Jim mentioned.

Comment: Did not check event viewer will do, @Andy i enabled FirstChanceException only to log error/exception detail to debug window and is enabled only for debug. When deploy its commented.
Any other comments?

Comment: Event Log has nothing in it. Where else can we look? I donot have unmanaged code too.